# Suppose that an $n \times n$ matrix has only real eigenvalues. Then $A$ is diagonalizable if and only if the dimension..

Tags: linear-algebra, examples-counterexamples

Suppose that an $n \times n$ matrix has only real eigenvalues. Then $A$ is diagonalizable if and only if the dimension of each eigenspace is equal to the multiplicity of the corresponding eigenvalue.

Why do we need the eigenvalues to be real here? I'm reading the proof of this and it seems like the same argument could be applied even if we had complex eigenvalues.

Comment: Matrices with complex eigenvalues that satisfy the multiplicity condition are diagonalizable over $\mathbb{C}$, but not $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: OOOoooooh right... Thank you!!